Unable to load dynamic library 'oci8_19' in PHP 8
I have a virtual machine with three differents versions of PHP (8.1.25, 7.4.0 and 5.5.0) and my database is Oracle.
Everytime I try running a code using the oracle database in a ".bat" file, it give-me this error:

PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function oci_connect() in C:\xampp\htdocs\bcenter\conexoes\conecta_oracle_hml.php:3 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\bcenter\infobip\recepcao_exames\hml\recep_exames_hml.php(12): conOracle() #1 {main}   thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\bcenter\conexoes\conecta_oracle_hml.php on line 3

This is an generic example of what I'm trying to run  using the ".bat" file:
include("../../../conexoes/conecta_oracle_hml.php");
    $conOracle  = conOracle();
    $select = "SELECT 1 AS DUMMY_DATA
                FROM DUAL
                WHERE 1=1";
    $parsi = oci_parse($conOracle,$select);
    oci_execute($parsi);
    while($row = oci_fetch_array($parsi,OCI_ASSOC)){
        $solic = $row['DUMMY_DATA'];
        echo($solic);
    }

But here lies the problem, everytime I run this on browser it works normally, like the example below:

From what I get, the prompt command error is saying that it couldn't find the "oci8_19" nor the "oci8_dll" on the directories they are supposed to be, but, I checked my "php.ini" and confirmed that the php extension is not deactivated and my oci8_19.dll is in the right directory.
Then, I tried to search for what could be causing this error and checked:

My oracle instant client version: - it's the 19_22 version

PATH environment variable: every version of PHP has a PATH defined

PATH environment variable: my oracle instant client has a path defined on it's folder.

My apache version is 2.4.8


I need the script to run on a ".bat" file because I will schedule it in windows scheduler to run at certain times, but since I'm gettting this error is not possible.

"is in the right directory" Which directory?

Please extract a [mcve] from your code, which includes how you run it.

Is PATH set in the bat file?  Is PATH set as a system level env var?  If all else fails, you could move the required Instant Client files to the PHP extension directory.  Note many of the Instant Client files aren't needed for PHP, e.g the jars
